# Facebook Pay Dialog : There Was a issue Processing Your Payment

Tags: facebook, dialog, payment

I have used the following code for open the Facebook Pay Dialog box for My application app on Facebook **but getting error :**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<p> <a onclick="placeOrder(); return false;">Buy</a></p>

<script> 
    FB.init({appId: 367311903326028, status: true, cookie: true});

    function placeOrder() {
      // If using mobile, this is where you place the
      // iOS native app check for credits (see below)

      // Assign an internal ID that points to a database record
      var order_info = 'abc123';

      // calling the API ...
      var obj = {
        method: 'pay',
        order_info: order_info,
        action: 'buy_item',
        dev_purchase_params: {'oscif': true}
      };

      FB.ui(obj, callback);
    }

    var callback = function(data) {
      if (data['order_id']) {
        return true;
      } else {
        //handle errors here
        return false;
      }
    };

    function writeback(str) {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=str;
    }
</script>

<br>
```

**Error :**

There Was a Problem Processing Your Payment 
Sorry, but we're having trouble processing your payment. 
You have not been charged for this transaction. Please try again.

Please can anyone suggest me what going wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Please consider to properly format the code next time

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it's really hard to know what the issue is here. Specifically, what response are you supplying to the payments_status_update request? Can you show us the code that handles those requests, or an example of your response?

I've personally seen that error message in cases where our callback was responding incorrectly to the payments_status_update request, but it could be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you are using the old currency payments, which is a bad idea as they are going to be deprecated in two months.

Check that in your FB App settings you are NOT using the new Local currency payments, as if you have it enabled (which is the default setting now), then the only way that you can make a purchase is with the new way. Using the old way will fail. 
Deactivating the new payment method will allow you to use BOTH the new and the old method.